# Trying to open a form using DoCmd.OpenForm based on sub form control

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an unbound form with an unbound control (Text0). In Text0 I enter a RefNo. I want to open another form (frmDisclosure) which has a subform (frmRefNosList) containing the RefNo. My code for opening frmDisclosure is: 
    Private Sub Command8_Click()

```
Dim Refce As Variant

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDisclosure"
Forms!frmDisclosure.FilterOn = False
Refce = "Forms!frmDisclosure!frmRefNosList.Form!RefNo"
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDisclosure", acNormal, "", Refce & " = " & Me.Text0, , acNormal

End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense. You are opening frmDisclosure twice, the second time applying a filter that is meaningless.

Comment: It makes mor sense that might be apparent. Form Disclosure normally opens with a filter, which, in other code that I use,has to be removed.'Opening it twice' works in other code. It seems that my 'Refce' is at fault. Remove the filter and I get a message that frm Disclosure can't be found.

Comment: The name of the control is the same.

Comment: Actually Gustav, I'm applying a Where condition, not a filter. so it's necessary to remove the filter that is always in place and open the form using the Where condition.

Comment: HansUp: Have a look at this:Debug.Print Forms!frmDisclosure!frmRefNosList!RefNo, TypeName(Forms!frmDisclosure!frmRefNosList!RefNo)
F0105228509   TextBox. The Ref No relates to the record that normally appears when the form opens - I don't know why.

Comment: What doesn't work is trying to open frmDisclosure where RefNo = the value of Text0 on my unbound form. I'm wondering if there is something wrong with 'Refce = Forms!frmDisclosure.frmRefNosList!RefNo'

Answer (score 1):

After our discussion in chat, I mocked-up something that hopefully looks like what you were trying to do:

[Link to Access file mock-up](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-J5B7nFljZiaEVMUWJlcFpwR3c/view?usp=sharing).

To others that might read this later here are a few clarifications:

- Form **Form1** has a textbox called **Text0** on it and a button.
- When the button is pressed it is supposed to open **Form2** that has a
  subform on it.
- **Form2** is then supposed to open to a certain record and then filter the
  records shown on its subform all using value provided in **Text0**

Here's what my mock-up of **Form1** looks like:

[image]

So when I provide a RefNo and click the button...

[image]

... the following code (annotated) is run on the click event of that button:

```vb
Private Sub cmdOpen_Click()

    ' check user has provided a RefNo in the textbox...
    If _
        Me.Text0 = "" Or _
        IsNull(Me.Text0) _
    Then

        ' ...if a RefNo has not been provided, give an error message
        MsgBox "Please provide a Ref No.", vbExclamation Or vbOKOnly, "Disclosure Search"

    Else

        ' ...if a RefNo has been provided, look in the table that lists an applicant's
        ' forms and return the ApplicantID (or equivalent field you're using) for the RefNo provided
        Dim varApplicantID As Variant
        varApplicantID = DLookup("ApplicantID", "tblRefNos", "RefNo=" & Me.Text0)

        ' ...check that an applicant record can be actually be found from the RefNo provided
        If _
            IsNull(varApplicantID) _
        Then

            '... if an applicant record is not found, give an error message
            MsgBox "Could not find an applicant with the RefNo provided.", vbExclamation Or vbOKOnly, "Disclosure Search"

        Else

            '... if an applicant record is found, open Form2 to that applicant's record
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", , , "ApplicantID=" & varApplicantID

            '... and then filter the subform on Form2 by the RefNo provided
            Forms!Form2!frmApplicantForms_sub.Form.Filter = "RefNo=" & Me.Text0
            Forms!Form2!frmApplicantForms_sub.Form.FilterOn = True
            Forms!Form2!frmApplicantForms_sub.Form.Requery

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

This should result in **Form2** opening to the correct applicant record derived from the RefNo provided and also filter the subform by the RefNo provided:

[image]

Your exact project layout may differ to what I've mocked-up, so some of this may need to be tweaked for your set up, but hopefully the principles I've illustrated here will be easy enough to translate.

Good luck!

Comment: Very Many thanks for this. I'll see how it works later.

Answer (score 0):

This was not the answer I wanted but: I created a query that yields the ID number of frmDisclosure corresponding to Text0 on the unbound form. I then retreive that ID number using DLookup from within the unbound form and open frmDisclosure that way. It would have been nicer to do it all from within the unbound form.

Comment: What you want to is more than likely possible, but you might have to make it clearer what you're trying to do. So far I think you've said you have Form1 with Text0 and you want to put a refno in Text0, press a button(?) and have that open Form2, which has a subform that has list that should(?) include a refno that you've put in Text0(?) Also, the argument 'Refce = Me.Text0' is a WHERE clause that relates to the form you are opening, therefore 'Refce' should be a field on your frmDisclosure form. Is it? It's confusing because you've also defined `Refce` as a variable in your VBA [continued...]

Comment: [...] The WHERE clause argument should surround references to the fields on the form you are opening in double quotes and then concatenate anything else not on that form e.g.: `"Refce = " & Me.Text0` (I've assumed that this is a number field; if it's text it will need to be written differently). I also think where you assign `Refce = Forms!frmDisclosure.frmRefNosList!RefNo`, it should be more like `Refce = Forms!frmDisclosure!frmRefNosList.Form!RefNo` (see this handy guide: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm).

Comment: Thank you Matt Hall. I have edited my question above. I have Form1 with Text0 and I put a RefNo in Text0, press a button (Command8) and want that to open Form2, which has a subform that has list that includes a RefNo that I have put in Text0.  'Refce = Me.Text0' is a WHERE clause that relates to the form I want to open. 'Refce' equates to a field (RefNo) on my frmDisclosure form. What I now get is Form2 Opens but with a window 'Enter parameter value F01056106. Blwo that the 'control' where I am expected to enter the parameter value. If I insert that data, Form2 opens in Add Mode.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want Form2 to open with its *subform* filtered to the record that matches the RefNo you entered in Form1's Text0 field?

Comment: Yes. The filter is the RefNo, which appears on the subform. The idea is that I get emails from organisations that specify the RefNo and I need to open Form2.

Comment: Final question (hopefully!): is RefNo also on Form2 as well as being listed on its subform? What fields link Form2 to its subform?

Comment: RefNo only appears on the sub form. Linkage: Master Field: ID; Child Field: DiscLookup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103082/discussion-between-matt-hall-and-great-crosby).

Comment: I have inputted your suggested procedure and mad the necessary changes. I get an error: 'Runtime error 2471. The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: "F0106144752"'. This is in response to this part of the code: varApplicantID = DLookup("DiscLookup", "tblForms", "RefNo=" & Me.Text0). I have triple-checked my changes to your code. F0106144752 is a genuine RefNo and is actually connected to an application. – Great Crosby 2 hours ago    However, your code led me to the answer. The DLookup gives the ID of Form2, so I can open it with just that.

Comment: Oh ok, your RefNo isn't a number, it's a string due to that "F". You have to do the DLookup like this: `varApplicantID = DLookup("ApplicantID", "tblRefNos", "RefNo='" & Me.Text0 & "'")` (note the single quotes needing to be included around `Me.Text0` to tell it that Text0 has a string value rather than a number).

Comment: Hi Matt. I figured out the string bit. I'd like to give you the credit for the solution - how?. Although I found a really simple solution, it was your comments that led me to it.)

Comment: Next to the top left of my answer should be an empty-looking tick. Click on that to turn it green and that accepts the answer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png